# Is there a way to make this nested forms been submitted with one click using htmx and django

Tags: jquery, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, htmx

So I have web page that contains many nested forms where I can add dynamically many forms by clicking a button and this form are import from other HTML templates to the main web page that can also duplicate many forms within it, but what I need is to make sure that every form will be submitted correctly!

The main HTML page that will contain the HTML page:

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>
            Create sessions for {{ course.name }}
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" hx-get="{% url 'create-session-form' %}" hx-target="#sessionforms" hx-swap="beforeend">
            Add Session
        </button>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="sessionforms">

</div>
<button type="submit" action="{% url 'submit-all' %}">
Submit the full form from here!
</button>
</form>
```

An example of the session_form HTML page:

```
 <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}

        <div class="mt-5 py-5 border-t border-gray-100">
            {% for assignment in assignments %}
        
            {% include "partials/assignment_detail.html" %}
        
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <button type="button" hx-get="{% url 'create-assignment-form' %}" hx-target="this" hx-swap="beforebegin">
        Add assignments for this session
        </button>
        <button type="button" hx-get="{% url 'create-learningoutcome-form' %}" hx-target="this" hx-swap="beforebegin">
        Add learning outcomes
        </button>


        {% if session %}
        <button type="submit" hx-post="{% url 'update-session' session.id %}">
            Submit
        </button>

        {% else %}
        <button type="submit" hx-post=".">
            Submit
        </button>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
```

And of course the outcomes HTML page example:

```
<div hx-target="this" hx-swap="outerHTML">
    <form method="POST">
        <table class="table table-auto">

            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {% for item in form.visible_fields %}
                            <td class="col-md-4" >{{item}}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
        {% if learningoutcome %}
        <button type="submit" hx-post="{% url 'update-learningoutcome' learningoutcome.id %}">
            Submit
        </button>
        <button hx-get="{% url 'detail-learningoutcome' learningoutcome.id %}" type="button">
            Cancel
        </button>
        {% else %}
        <button type="submit" hx-post=".">
            Submit
        </button>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
```

The views function are simple but if there any suggestion for the add-all view function? or any other solution by one click on the add-all button

I have tried to use jquery but it wasn't that simple especially I haven't specified every form and give it a unique name or id or class!

I want to delete the other specific submit and use only one!

Comment: I think that implementing "add another form" button using HTMX might be the wrong approach. You can create new forms of a formset by writing some JS that copies the `formset.empty_form` to the end of the formset div. It's more efficient since no request is made to the server. Regarding your code, you should strip `<form>` tags of form inside a formset. Nested form tags don't work well in HTML. Also, when adding another form, it's necessary to update the management form of the formset. So, in any case, looks like you need some JS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using a Javascript function as @vinkomlacic suggested in the comments and this by giving each form a class name, than submitting the data asynchronously, here is an example that loop at each form

```js
        const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-all-forms');
    
        submitButton.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const waitPanel = document.querySelector('#wait-panel');
        waitPanel.style.display = 'block';

        const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.submit-me');
    
        // loop through each form and submit it
        for (let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          const form = forms[i];
    
          try {
            await submitForm(form);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
          }
        }
        window.location.href = '/create-object/';
      });
    
      async function submitForm(form) {
        const formData = new FormData(form);
    
        // send the form data to the server
        const response = await fetch(form.action, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
        });
    
        // throw an error if the response is not OK
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(response.statusText);
        }
      }
```